# Writing test cases for scheduled jobs

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
@Singleton
public class ScheduledJob {

    @Schedule(minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void doWork(){
        System.out.println("Running at: " +LocalDate.now());
    }
}
```

I would be glad to know if we can write Junit test cases for the class.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: "I would be glad to know if we can write Junit test cases for the class." why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your job is scheduled is not relevant to your testing of the functionality.  You're not testing the scheduling framework, you're testing your own business logic.

Therefore unit testing becomes simple:

```
@Inject
private ScheduledJob job;

@Test
public void testLogic() {
    //Do whatever testing you need...
    job.doWork();
}
```

You'll know whether you've configured the scheduling framework properly if your (well tested) service method gets called once it's deployed into whatever container you are using.